# Application which will update a website

Tags: android, sql, web

I would like to create an android application which would update the data on the website. The actual thing I want to do is create an android application which will let the user enter the scores of a live cricket match and onces the user clicks update the data should be updated on the website too. Please be as specific as possible because I'm a newbie.

Comment: How do you want to do that? By FTP, SQL? How is the website built? Do you database or static webpage? Do you use any CMS? ...

Comment: Well i dont mind any way. i already mentioned im a newbie soo whatever steps you tell me il go learn them and then start building it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you to create webpage with MySQL database, which will store the scores. Then in PHP, for example, you can make the site, which will show them.

---

Introduction to MySQL with PHP: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Introduction to PHP: http://php.net//manual/pl/tutorial.php

---

To send data from Android application I suggest you to create JSON API (best in POST sending format) on the website's server. That API will authenticate user and after validation put data to the database.

---

There you have got tutorial, how to create simple JSON PHP API using MySQL database: http://www.brenelz.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-api-with-php-and-mysql/

How to send data from Android application in JSON format to the API http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/

Comment: @user3760831 If you think, my answer was the best and fully answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking a tick near my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest making a REST API that receives all your data and a website that drives off the database information.

Here's a tutorial on how to call a REST api:
http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes

Here's a tutorial on how to create the php Rest api:
http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Your android app would call the REST api and the rest api would get those variables you passed in and insert them into a table. Your website would then dynamically generate its content based on those values.

Personally I'm using WordPress and Custom Plugins to do all that...

Comment: could you please be more specific ? im a newbie.

Comment: @CTravel It was an answer on how to do it. I didnt critique or request clarification. I gave him a generic answer to a generic question.

Comment: @CTravel Because that's all it needed. There are many questions out there answering his generic problem. All he needed to know was what its called in order to research it himself.

Comment: @jcaruso oke, but dont think i voted your answer down, just reviewed it..

Comment: Yes jcaruso i definately have a good idea on how to carry on my idea.

Comment: @user3760831 Awesome! Glad you got what you needed